Изменение GET запросов при проксировании
Есть приложение в докере, которое работает с помощью GET запросов. Внешняя система отправляет запрос вида /api/results?apikey=321&Query=ABC&genres=&Category[]=5000 мне же нужно убрать из него последний параметр &Category[]=5000 и получить следущий запрос /api/results?apikey=321&Query=ABC&genres=. Цифры после Category могут меняться, этот блок может вообще отсутствовать. Возможности изменить внешнюю систему и приложение нет. Я развернул Apache и настроил на нем обратный прокси вот с такими настройками
<VirtualHost *:5115>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://myip:6116/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://myip:6116/
</VirtualHost>

Но вот как обрезать входящий url я не разобрался. Прошу помощи. Использование Апача не принципиально. Если можно сделать через nginx без проблем перейду на него.
